# FormEncode is returning my file upload as a Unicode object - How fix?

Tags: python, file-upload, pylons, formencode

```
<form action="${h.url.current()}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="your_file" />
</form>

class MyValidator(formencode.Schema):

    allow_extra_fields  = True
    filter_extra_fields = True

    name      = formencode.validators.String(not_empty=True, messages={'empty': 'Please enter your name'})
    your_file = formencode.validators.FieldStorageUploadConverter(not_empty=True, messages={'empty': 'You haven\'t selected any files'})


try:
    form_result = MyValidator().to_python(dict(request.params))
except formencode.Invalid as error:
    return 'failed'
else:
    print type(form_result['your_file'])
```

That's my code. `form_result['your_file']` is a Unicode object. Because of this, I can't read the file or do any 'file' related tasks. The only way I've found to access it is to abandon formencode after it's performed its validation and revert to `request.POST['your_file']`.

What am I doing wrong?